# live migration in cloudsim?

Tags: migration, virtual-machine, live

Can someone please explain how to implement live VM migration in cloudsim?
I am trying to implement pre copy algorithm in cloudsim, I have created a VM with certain memory and has assigned boolean values if the pages in the memory is dirtied or not. I am not sure if I am in the right track. please help

Comment: seriously, no response? I have the same question